# How to write a case Maybe statement using where

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, I am trying to write something like

```
function x = do
    y <- get x
    put y
    let z = Map.lookup y
    case y of 
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just y -> do... (something)
```

I want to replace the "let..case of" block with something like a "where..case of" block or "where" block if possible. How can I do so?

Comment: Isn't this `case z of`?

Comment: No, what i am trying to do is put the value of Map.lookup y into a value as I cannot return it because y has cases(as I have shown).. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The `case` statement isn't inside the `let` declaration. the `let` declaration only contains `let z = Map.lookup y`. The `case` is a subsequent monadic action.

Comment: `(something)` is probably something you can `fmap` over `z` directly: `fmap (...) (Map.lookup y)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function with pattern matching in a `where` block. (I don't know, if it is a better solution because you didn't explain very well what does the function do, but it is possible):

```hs
function x = do
    y <- get x
    put y
    let z = Map.lookup y
    fn y
    where fn Nothing = Nothing
          fn (Just n) = do... (something)
```

Also, note that you can use `fmap`:

```hs
function x = do
    y <- get x
    put y
    let z = Map.lookup y
    fmap fn y
    where fn n = do... (something)
```